# bootstrap.css and IE11 issues

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working on an AngularJS app using bootstrap.css. Everything looks great in chrome but I get formatting issues in both firefox and IE11.

HEAD

```
        <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Application</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
     <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.js"
</script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="js/dirPagination.js"></script>
<script src="app/myAppAccounts.js"></script>
<base href="/">
</head>
```

What it looks like:
[image]
Any tips on fixing this?

EDIT

As requested HTML for buttons. These are in a partial.

```
   <div class="col-md-2">
      <input ng-model="dateFrom" type="date" class="form-control">
    </div>
     <div  class="col-md-2">
      <input ng-model="dateTo" type="date" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <button class="form-control" type="button" ng-click="searchByDate(dateFrom, dateTo)" > Search </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3" >
        <input ng-model="orderID" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search by order ID">

     </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
       <button class="form-control" type="button" ng-click="searchByID()"> Search </button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you show us the html for those buttons?

Comment: Yup done, there you go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've mainly seen this occur when trying to use things within a col-md-1 div. The contents traditionally exceed the width of the container and as such the buttons are the correct size, but the text is not truncated, and the overflow is shown.

I have modified a little bit of your html to maybe work a little better:

[Plnkr Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/kqbykS?p=preview)

[image]

```
<div class="col-md-12 ">
  <div class="col-md-6 text-left">
     <div class="col-md-4">
       <input ng-model="dateFrom" type="date" class="form-control"  placeholder="Start Date">  
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
       <input ng-model="dateTo" type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="End Date">
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
       <button class="form-control" type="button" ng-click="searchByDate(dateFrom, dateTo)" > Search </button>
     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
     <div class="col-md-8" >
       <input ng-model="orderID" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search by order ID">
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
      <button class="form-control" type="button" ng-click="searchByID()"> Search </button>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this I hadn't thought of that I actually got buttons working ok by removing the form-control class and doing    <a  class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="searchByDate(dateFrom, dateTo)" > Search </a>

This works good on all browsers, the date picker is nackered though

Comment: That being said i've just started playing with ui.bootstrap instead of using the standard CSS although I have yet another reason to HATE, HATE, HATE IE because if chrome can render a standard CSS date picker why can't IE11?!

Comment: Upvoted for pointing out the obvious which i'd completely missed :-)

Comment: @MrkFldig Ya, the benefit of utilizing my changes and yours is the responsiveness you get when you start sliding the html window left and right. You can see how differently they behave.

Comment: I'm marking as correct any ideas on the datepicker though please? The ui.bootstrap one seems like a lot of code for a datepicker!

Comment: @MrkFldig I've used the ui.bootstrap/AngularUI directives in the past and they are great. You may think that you can avoid them, but they will end up saving you a lot of time if you have access to them going forward.